# Get value of Javascript object property based on the values of two other properties in that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given the array of objects below, what is a better way to get an array of 'thirdId's given that the first two ids match what is passed into the method?

```js
const arrObjs = 
[ { firstId: '1', secondId: '1', thirdId: '5' },
  { firstId: '2', secondId: '1', thirdId: '12' },
  { firstId: '1', secondId: '2', thirdId: '13' },
  { firstId: '1', secondId: '1', thirdId: '42' },
  { firstId: '1', secondId: '2', thirdId: '51' } ];
  
const getThirdIds = (arrObjs, firstId, secondId ) => {
  const thirdIds = []

  arrObjs.map(obj => {
      if (obj.firstId == firstId && obj.secondId == secondId) {
        thirdIds.push(obj.thirdId)
      }
  })

  return thirdIds
}

console.log(getThirdIds(arrObjs, 1, 1));
```

I'd like to keep away from loDash. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a filter then map, ie

```
return arrObjs
  .filter(obj => obj.firstId == firstId && obj.secondId == secondId)
  .map(obj => obj.thirdId)
```

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) will create a new array with only the matching entries.

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) will then convert that array into one only containing the `thirdId` property from each entry.

---

If you're not keen on performing two sets of iterations (filter and map), you could use an [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) operation

```
return arrObjs.reduce((/* collector */ thirdIds, /* each */ obj) => {
  if (obj.firstId == firstId && obj.secondId == secondId) {
    thirdIds.push(obj.thirdId)
  }
  return thirdIds
}, /* initial collector value */ [])
```

Answer (score 1):

If "better" means shorter:

```js
const arrObjs = 
[ { firstId: '1', secondId: '1', thirdId: '5' },
  { firstId: '2', secondId: '1', thirdId: '12' },
  { firstId: '1', secondId: '2', thirdId: '13' },
  { firstId: '1', secondId: '1', thirdId: '42' },
  { firstId: '1', secondId: '2', thirdId: '51' } ]
  
const getThirdIds = (a, b, c) => a.reduce((r, o) => 
            o.firstId == b && o.secondId == c ? r.concat(o.thirdId) : r, [])

console.log(getThirdIds(arrObjs, 1, 1))
```

---

If "better" means more efficient, a lookup object can be created for a constant O(1) search:

```js
const arrObjs = [ { firstId: '1', secondId: '1', thirdId: '5' },
                  { firstId: '2', secondId: '1', thirdId: '12' },
                  { firstId: '1', secondId: '2', thirdId: '13' },
                  { firstId: '1', secondId: '1', thirdId: '42' },
                  { firstId: '1', secondId: '2', thirdId: '51' } ];

const lookup = []
for (let i = 0; i < arrObjs.length; i++) 
{
   const obj = arrObjs[i], 
   lookup1 = lookup [obj.firstId ] || (lookup [obj.firstId ] = []), 
   lookup2 = lookup1[obj.secondId] || (lookup1[obj.secondId] = [])
   lookup2[lookup2.length] = +obj.thirdId
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(lookup))         // lookup = [,[,[5,42],[13,51]],[,[12]]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(lookup[1][1]))   // [5,42]
```